# Changing turtle look direction in Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

In python's turtle graphics, i am having a turtle run through the 'for' loop. It is important that at the end, the turtle is looking the same direction as when it started, how can this be done with the following code:

```
 for x in range (op):
 x=random.randint(1,inp)
 kjr.speed(0)
 kjr.begin_fill()
 kjr.pendown()
 color=random.choice(cr)
 kjr.color(color)
 kjr.forward(x)
 kjr.left(90)
 y=random.randint(1,inptwo)
 kjr.forward(y)
 kjr.left(90)
 kjr.forward(x)
 kjr.left(90)
 kjr.forward(y)
 kjr.end_fill()
 kjr.penup()
 kjr.goto(x,y)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# store the value
heading = turtle.heading()    
...
# for loop
... 
turtle.seth( heading )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the initial position of your turtle. You can do something like this

```
heading = turtle.heading()
```

then run through the for loop with your turtle

```
for x in range (op):
  x=random.randint(1,inp)
  kjr.speed(0)
  kjr.begin_fill()
  kjr.pendown()
  color=random.choice(cr)
  kjr.color(color)
  kjr.forward(x)
  kjr.left(90)
  y=random.randint(1,inptwo)
  kjr.forward(y)
  kjr.left(90)
  kjr.forward(x)
  kjr.left(90)
  kjr.forward(y)
  kjr.end_fill()
  kjr.penup()
  kjr.goto(x,y)
```

and once you are done go back to initial position

```
turtle.seth(heading)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you want to restore the heading as the last step of your loop, or restore it after the loop completes. If you want to do it within the loop, since you do three right angles, `kjr.left(90)`, you only need do a fourth to return your heading to where you started:

```
kjr.speed('fasest')

for x in range(op):
    x = random.randint(1, inp)

    color = random.choice(cr)
    kjr.color(color)
    kjr.pendown()

    kjr.begin_fill()
    kjr.forward(x)
    kjr.left(90)
    y = random.randint(1, inptwo)
    kjr.forward(y)
    kjr.left(90)
    kjr.forward(x)
    kjr.left(90)
    kjr.forward(y)
    kjr.end_fill()

    kjr.penup()
    kjr.goto(x, y)
    kjr.left(90)  # make turtle look in same direction as top of loop
```

You don't need save and restore the heading in this case.  However, if you want to restore the heading ***after*** the loop, then you are best off saving the heading, not the position, before the loop, and restoring the heading after the loop as @mko (+1) suggests.